# How does high feedback resistor (gain) affect offset voltage or noise?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors

I wanted to get some insight on how high feedback resistor or high gain can affect offset voltage/ noise of an op-amp. I'm using 100M ohm as my feedback resistor for LMC6001, will it increase offset voltage/noise? If so then how is it related? Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Kindly share your circuit.

Comment: Higher resistance means higher thermal noise in general.  A feedback resistor will not affect the input-referred offset voltage of an op-amp, but if it means higher gain the offset at the output will be higher.  Other than that it's hard to say more without a specific circuit.